# Rails HTML/TEXT UserMailer Templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

Currently for my Rails 3 mailer templates, I need to create an `html` and `text` version in the `views/user_mailer directory`.

Why is that necessary? Why can't rails look at the `html` version and automatically format it to a `text/plain` version?

Comment: How could rails transform html to text automatically? do you know rules about that? Inversely, if ever you can transform text to html, please tell me, it will save me the money I spend in web design.

Comment: Sure turn a <BR> or <P> into a /r or /n for example.... Turn LIs in to *

Comment: what about divs with margin and padding, tables etc...? It could be really dangerous to let Rails decide for you.

Comment: for a mailer template, providing a easy text version, I don't know if I agree if that being "dangerous"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not required. You can simply provide one of those templates. For instance, if you don't need HTML, you can create the TEXT file only.

Likewise, you can provide the HTML template only. Readers will attempts to extract the information.
However, if you use HTML, you *should* provide an alternative TEXT version to make sure the readers won't mess the content of your email.

By the way, Rails doesn't force you to provide both templates.

Comment: Thanks Simone, that I get. I have both versions. What I'm getting at is if I have an HTML version, why can't a TEXT version be genereated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

This question seems to be similar to yours and might be helpful to you:

[Graceful degradation/progressive enhancement for Action Mailer templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248790/graceful-degradation-progressive-enhancement-for-action-mailer-templates)

Also, here are some direct links to some gems that help to solve this problem of duplication between html and text mailer templates:

1. https://github.com/plataformatec/markerb
2. https://github.com/Mange/roadie
3. https://github.com/fphilipe/premailer-rails3