# Do providing plain text email form ensures us that recipient will get version he can properly show?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

By default Rails mailers provides us with two email forms: the `html` one and the `text` one. In [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4908548/3668967) post I found such a sentence:

> However, if you use html, you should provide an alternative text
>   version to make sure the readers won't mess the content of your email.

Does it really work that way? And if so, how does it work exactly? I can see that in my `mail.body` I have only my `html` version included, so that's not sended in both versions at once. So, in what circumstances my `text` form can be used when I have set the `html` one by default? How can I test it?

Answer (score 1):

If the email is sent as a multipart email then the email client can select which format of the email it will display.

Some clients even use both but in different contexts such as phones that display the text version in banners and notifications. Failure to provide a plain text version can often result in the raw html being displayed.

A multipart email is just an email with `Content-Type: multipart/alternative;` and each part is separated by the string provided in the `Boundry` header.

```
X-sender: <sender@sendersdomain.com>
X-receiver: <somerecipient@recipientdomain.com>
From: "Senders Name" <sender@sendersdomain.com>
To: "Recipient Name" <somerecipient@recipientdomain.com>
Message-ID: <5bec11c119194c14999e592feb46e3cf@sendersdomain.com>
Date: Sat, 24 Sep 2005 15:06:49 -0400
Subject: Sample Multi-Part
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; 
boundary="----=_NextPart_DC7E1BB5_1105_4DB3_BAE3_2A6208EB099D"

------=_NextPart_DC7E1BB5_1105_4DB3_BAE3_2A6208EB099D
Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Sample Text Content
------=_NextPart_DC7E1BB5_1105_4DB3_BAE3_2A6208EB099D
Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div style=3D"FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial">Sample HTML =
Content</div>
</body>
</html>

------=_NextPart_DC7E1BB5_1105_4DB3_BAE3_2A6208EB099D--
```

> How can I test it?

Depends entirely on the email client / device.

- [Outlook](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/read-email-messages-in-plain-text-16dfe54a-fadc-4261-b2ce-19ad072ed7e3)
- [Gmail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/26732/show-text-part-of-a-multipart-email-in-gmail)
- [Thunderbird](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Plain_text_e-mail_(Thunderbird))

If you want to test it with MiniTest/RSpec you can get the different parts of the email with:

```
message.text_part
message.html_part
```

You can parse the `html_part` with Nokogiri or use [Capybara](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/use-capybara-on-any-html-fragment-or-page) to navigate it just like it was a page:

```
page = Capybara::Node::Simple.new(message.html_part)
assert page.has_content?("Hello World!")
```

Comment: In some projects I have written the emails as markdown and used redcarpet to convert the emails to HTML. This avoids duplicating the contents for most simple email messages.